# Difficulty in acquiring inspect element code through scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I have written a small code to **scrape** the inspect element code to apply css or xpath selectors from this website https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:-12.0/centery:25.0/zoom:4. Now, I am unable to get that code, I am getting page source code instead. As, I am novice in Python, not able to figure out what to do.
I am attaching my code here.

```
import scrapy 
class MarineSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "marine"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers=headers)
    def parse(self, response):
        file_name = 'innercode.html'
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Comment: @Gallaecio Yeah exactly, this code is working perfectly fine for inspecting [link](quotestoscrape.com) but when it comes to [link](marinetraffic.com), it sucks. Any idea?

Comment: The link points to “Caveats with inspecting the live browser DOM”, which explains that what the “Inspect” feature of a web browser shows is seldom what the underlying HTML contains. Maybe this would be more helpful: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: @Gallaecio thanks for the help!